# Run multiple functions continuously in an infinite loop

Tags: php, function, symfony

I have five php class, and I want to run 5 function continuously(endless)from those 5 php classes in the start of my application or execute all those 5 function inside of a php class, where in will run continuously and all of them.
Here is the 5 classes and those 5 function. I am working on symfony2 framework.

```
$val1 = new phpClass1();
$val1->phpClass1Action();

$val2 = new phpClass2();
$val2->phpClass2ction();

$val3 = new phpClass3();
$val3->phpClass3Action();

$val4 = new phpClass4();
$val4->phpClass4Action();

$val5 = new phpClass5();
$val5->phpClass5Action();
```

Do anyone have any suggestion how I am execute this function.
Thanks a lot in Advanced.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php It's called threading. have fun reading the manual.

Comment: Do you want to run all these functions in parallel or continuously in an infinite loop?

Comment: I want to run those function continuously in an infinite loop @MichaelSivolobov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run these functions continuously in infinite loop you need to set time limit to infinity and run a loop:

```
set_time_limit(0);

while (true) {
    $val1 = new phpClass1();
    $val1->phpClass1Action();

    $val2 = new phpClass2();
    $val2->phpClass2ction();

    $val3 = new phpClass3();
    $val3->phpClass3Action();

    $val4 = new phpClass4();
    $val4->phpClass4Action();

    $val5 = new phpClass5();
    $val5->phpClass5Action();
}
```

Comment: i have actually tried like that before but it doesn't help, it actually execute the 1st function and never run the rest of the other function's

Comment: Could you then please show us the code of the first method `phpClass1::phpClass1Action`?

Comment: class phpClass1 extends Controller {

    public function phpClass1Action() {
    set_time_limit(0);
    $val = $this->MyFunction();
    .......
    while (true) {
    ......
    }
        return new Response('done');
    }

    function MyFunction(){
    .....
    foreach (........) {
    .....
    return status;
    }
    
    }

Comment: Your phpClass1Action() itself contains an infinite loop and unless you use threads it's not asynchronous. Therefore program control is never returned from that method and the subsequent code which calls the other four methods is not executed.